# MS Teams: Office 365 Connector redirects to localhost instead of Jenkins URL

Tags: jenkins, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to setup a simple job in Jenkins with Office 365 Connector plugin. When the job build is finished, I want Jenkins to send the build result to my Microsoft Teams channel.

Here's my Jenkins setup: (I followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/configure-jenkins-notifications-with-microsoft-tea))

[image: Here's my Jenkins setup]

Everything works fine except for the message sent to MS team: it directs `View Build` to `localhost:8080` instead of Jenkins URL.

[image: it directs <code>View Build</code> to localhost:8080 instead of Jenkins URL.]

Where can I configure the link to my Jenkins URL?

Comment: The O365 connector plugin apparently used something called “Display URL Provider”. Maybe it can be configured somehow.

Comment: You need to set the Jenkins URL in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL.

Comment: @jayhendren thanks, that works. I'll add it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer: You need to set the Jenkins URL in Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089566/jenkins-website-root-path